# Cannot dynamically pass a prop to a component within a v-for loop in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I have an array `sheets` initialised in data, has an item pushed to it when a button is pressed

```
data() {
    return {
        sheets: []
    };
}
```

And in the html I'm trying to add a `Card` component for each element in this array and pass the data as a prop, but none of the components get rendered and there is no error message. I also tried putting the `v-for` directly on the component but it has the same result

```
<div id="sheets">
    <template v-for="c in sheets">
        <Card :info="c"/>
    </template>
</div>
```

Meanwhile if I do something like this, it displays all the data in the array correctly, so I dont understand whats going wrong here

```
<div id="sheets">
    <template v-for="c in sheets">
        <span>{{c}}</span>
    </template>
</div>
```

--

**Solution**
In my component the data from prop was being manipulated in the created() function, it works after I did this in the mounted() function instead

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please add your code implemented in the `Card` component?

Comment: `key` is mandatory btw, it's not a nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have following things done **correctly**:

1. Imported your `Card` component
2. Passing and accessing the `props`
3. There are no conflicts in the variable names and id names

Next thing you need to know and **is a must** while using `v-for` is adding `:key` to the element which acts as unique id and lets `Vue` detect that each element is unique inside the `v-for`. One thing to be noted while using `:key` is that, you cannot use `:key` on the `<template>` tag.

Adding a validation using `v-if` would be a good idea, so `v-for` only executes if the array is not empty.

```js
<div id="sheets">
    <template v-if="sheets.length">
        <Card v-for="(sheet,index) in sheets" :key="index" :info="sheet" />
    </template>
</div>
```

**Edit 1:** As mentioned by **Michal** in the comments section that using `index` can lead to difficulties while debugging issues. You can use either `:key="sheet"` or if `sheet` is object including some unique `id` in it, then use `:key="sheet.id"` and get rid of the `index`

```js
// use this if sheet is not an object
<div id="sheets">
    <template v-if="sheets.length">
        <Card v-for="sheet in sheets" :key="sheet" :info="sheet" />
    </template>
</div>
```

**OR**

```js
// use this if sheet is an object having some unique id in it
<div id="sheets">
    <template v-if="sheets.length">
        <Card v-for="sheet in sheets" :key="sheet.id" :info="sheet" />
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that using index as `key` is generally bad idea and can lead to a very hard to debug problems\

Comment: @MichalLevý *Noted* sir. Something new for me as well as I never got into debugging problems because of it. I am aware that we can use some unique id as well that we have either inside the object or the element of the array itself, but mostly I use `index`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am curious why is `key` a must? I was able to find a fix without it so wondering what it actually does

Comment: I have already mentioned in the answer. As when the `v-for` is used, same HTML elements inside the `v-for` is generated multiple times. There must be something unique to make each dynamically generated element different and that is done with the help of `:key`. For better understanding you can refer [here](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html) in the docs as well.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote

Answer (score 0):

As `:key` is not mandatory, It should work without that as well. I just created a working fiddle below. Please have a look and try to find out the root cause.

```js
Vue.component('card', {
  props: ['info'],
  template: '<span>{{ info }}</span>',
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        sheets: [],
      count: 0
  },
  methods: {
    create() {
      this.count++;
        this.sheets.push('Sheet' + this.count);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="create">Create a Card!</button>
  <template v-for="c in sheets">
    <Card :info="c"></Card>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: `:key` is not mandatory but IMHO one must use it because `:key` with `v-for` is standard and best practice.

Comment: @Shreeraj Yeah that's correct. I mean that this issue is not related to `:key` attribute. I think I did not convey that properly.

Comment: yep. the question was missing a part of code where the `props` was being accessed. I just mentioned it in the answer that make sure the `props` are accessed correctly and along with it I thought to share the importance of `:key` while using `v-for`. I hope that makes sense.